# Distribution of Brownian Motion help

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, covariance

If $X = \frac{B_1 - B_3 + B_2}{\sqrt{2}}$
Where $B_t$ is brownian motion at time $t$.

And I want to find the the distribution of $X$, how would I do so?

$E[X] = 0$ is fairly straight forward.

For variance, however, I run into difficulty in treating:

\begin{equation*}
Var(B_1 - B_3 + B_2) = Var( (B_1-B_3) + B_2)) = Var(B_1 - B_3) + Var(B_2) + 2Cov(B_1-B_3,B_2)
\end{equation*}

But $Var(B_1 - B_3)$ isn't defined... is it?

Is there something I am missing, another method to calculate the variance of $X$ ?
Edit:

\begin{equation*}Var(X) = \frac{1}{2} [ Var(B_1 - B_3 + B_2)] = 0.5 [ Var( (B_1-B_3) + B_2))] = 0.5[Var(B_1 - B_3) + Var(B_2) + 2Cov(B_1-B_3,B_2)]
 =  0.5 [ Var(B_1) + Var(B_3) + Var(B_2) + 2Cov(B_1-B_3,B_2) -2Cov(B_1,B_3)]= 2 ?
\end{equation*}

Comment: $B_t$ is normally distributed with variance $t$. So $Var(B_1-B_3)$ is defined. It's the variance of the difference of 2 normally distributed random variables.

What I'm a little confused on is where "B-2" is coming from, and then randomly a B-3.

Comment: @Brenton, probably Latex issues?

Comment: @Brenton Sorry, hit $-$ instead of _. 
Further, given $B_t$ and $B_s$, I thought $B_t - B_s$ was normally distributed as $N(0,t-s)$ but only for $s \leq t$.
I may be rusty... Is it true that :
Is it true that $Var(B_1 - B_3) = Var(B_1) + Var(B_3) $ ?

Comment: $Var(B_1 - B_3) = Var(B_1) + Var(B_3) - 2Cov(B_1,B_3)$

Comment: Thanks brenton!

The answer I got is $2$ in that case, is this correct? (using $-2 Cov$)

Comment: There's a typo, it should be $-2 \text{Cov}(B_1,B_3)$ instead.

Comment: Whoops, thanks! I edited it.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $X = \frac{B_1 - B_3 + B_2}{\sqrt{2}}$. Since $B$ is a Brownian motion, you know that $B_3-B_2$ and $B_1$ are independent. Thus

$$\text{var}(X) = \frac{1}{2}\text{var}(B_1-B_3+B_2)=\frac{1}{2}\text{var}(B_1-(B_3-B_2))=\frac{1}{2}(\text{var}(B_1)+\text{var}(B_3-B_2)).$$

By definition, the increments $B_s-B_t$ are normally distributed with distribution $N(0,s-t)$ ($s\geq t$), whence $\text{var}(B_s-B_t) = s-t$. Completing the calculation for $\text{var}(X)$, it follows that
$$\text{var}(X) = \frac{1}{2}(\text{var}(B_1)+\text{var}(B_3-B_2)) = \frac{1}{2}(1+1)=1.$$

(Recall that $B_1 = B_1-B_0$, and thus $\text{var}(B_1) = 1-0=1$)